# Pass extra parameter to PHP Laravel Controller, based on URL

Tags: php, laravel, url, parameters, controller

I have competition website, where I use web routes like this:

```
Route::get('results/{year?}', 'Results')->where('year', '[0-9]+');
```

This allows to sneak-peak into current year "unpublished" results, just by "hacking" URL.
I'd like to create custom routes for every year, so after I want publish results - I change routes file only. Is it possible in Laravel?

I red Laravel docs and tried to search for this problem, yet I was unable to find exact query for my problem, as there is lots of other similar questions with extra parameters.

I tried to experiment with possible route definitions, something like this, which do not work:

```
Route::get('results_2023', 'Results', ['year' => 2023])->where('year', '[0-9]+');
Route::get('results_2024', 'Results', ['year' => 2024])->where('year', '[0-9]+');
```

What I do not want - it's redirect (URL transformation), so anyone using URL results_2025 would be redirect to results/2025, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Why not just add a validation check inside of the controller that the year is not in the future?

Comment: As aynber mentioned, add a validation into your controller to check the year, rather than hard-coding the routes

Comment: I'd like not to modify controller every time, as testing is not for exact day (like "if year is 2025"), but if results are confirmed, which are different day every year.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use the `defaults` method of the `Route` object to set default parameters that will be passed to the action:

```
Route::get('results_2023', 'Results')->defaults('year', 2023);
```

Comment: This was exactly the solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I would advice not to always change the route nor the controller for that matter. But you can add a custom validation inside the controller's method.

### **web.php**

```
Route::get('results/{year}', [ResultController::class, 'result']);
```

### **ResultController.php**

```
    public function result(Request $request, $year)
    {
        $validateYear = $this->validateResultYear($year);
        
        if ($validateYear->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $validateYear->errors()], 400);
        }

        // Validation passed, proceed with your logic
        switch ($year) {
            // ... switch cases based on year value
            // do something based on year
            // again use custom methods here per year if needed so that code is cleaner
        }

        // Return response or render view
    }

    public function validateResultYear($year)
    {

        // maybe add an if/else or switch here to make the rules dynamic based on current year/or if results are released.
        // rules
        $rules = [
            'year' => 'required|integer|min:1900|max:2100', // adjust rules
        ];

        // messages
        $messages = [
            'year.required' => 'The year is required.',
            'year.integer' => 'The year must be an integer.',
            'year.min' => 'The year must be at least :min.',
            'year.max' => 'The year must not be greater than :max.',
        ];

        // create array
        $arrValidate = ['year' => $year];

        // validate
        $validator = \Validator::make($arrValidate, $rules, $messages);

        return $validator;
    }
```

Did not test code but it should be enough for you to edit and get the result you want.

Comment: Why would you create a new Request?

Comment: used for validation in `Validator`.

Comment: but you are just passing an array to the validator ... why would you put that into a Request to extract it back as an array with `all` (giving you the same exact array you started with)?  basically why the extra work for the same exact result :-)

Comment: I see. I always think that to use validator, I need to use request.

Comment: change to use array instead

Answer (score 0):

As mention by other answer, you can use `defaults` method for passing parameter value from your route to your controller.

but just additional thing,
assume you have in your controller

```
public function index( Request $request, $year ) {
    return [
        'year' => $year
   ];
}
```

you should either remove the optional year

```
// only support year from 2000 - 2023, add 19\d{2} if you want to support year from 1900-1999
Route::get('results/{year}', [Result::class, 'index'])
    ->where('year', '(20[01]\d|202[0-3])');
```

or have the year optional but provide a default value if you want the `/results` to have a default year

```
Route::get('results/{year?}', [Result::class, 'index'])
    ->where('year', '(20[01]\d|202[0-3])')
    ->defaults('year', now()->format('Y') );
```

Then for additional routes without year parameter, just provide a default year value

```
Route::get('results_2023', [Result::class, 'index'])->defaults('year', 2023);
Route::get('results_2024', [Result::class, 'index'])->defaults('year', 2024);
```